# Learning Regex Backreferencing, and I don't understand what's going on

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

```
str2=re.match("\W(.)\1\W", " f\x01 ")
print(str2)

OUPUT: <re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match=' f\x01 '>
```

This doesn't work when I change the 'x' in the input string to 'y' or any other letter, and returns NONE for `str2=re.match("\W(.)\1\W", " f\y01 ")`

```
str2=re.match("\W(.)\1\W", " ff ")
print(str2)

OUTPUT: None
```

So since the only thing changing between these pieces of code is the string being inputted to compare with the RE. As I understand it, the RE means:
[^a-zA-Z0-9_] + Any Character(s) + [^a-zA-Z0-9_], so I don't understand why  these patterns don't both match the RE.

I'm working in Jupyter Notebook if that might somehow affect it. I'm sorry if this is something really obvious / amateurish that I've overlooked, and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's OK, it is just missing `r`:

```
import re

str2=re.match(r"\W(.)\1\W", " ff ")
print(str2)
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/R6xChP/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/R6xChP/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---